# SSAS Data Mining Time Series Model SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssas

Hope someone can help me:

I've created 4 Data Mining Structures with models in SSAS

[image: Screenshot 1]

2 of them contain a Time Series Algorithm, the other two Decision Trees.
Now when I want to create a Data Mining Query Task in SSIS, I only see -- in case of the 2 time seriers structures/models -- only the structure, not the model in the dialog box

[image: Screenshot 2]

While with the 2 other mining structures (containing decision trees) the mining model is displayed in the SSIS dialog box.

When I enter a query code in the data mining query task with the time series structures selected in SSIS (which is running fine in SSAS), I get the following error message in SSIS:

```
Error: 0x0 at Data Mining Query Task: Failed to execute data mining query due to the following error: The 'AdomdDataReader' data type is unsupported.
Task failed: Data Mining Query Task".
```

Is there a special way in SSIS for time series models? Can anyone help?

thanks and br

christoph

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved: Obviously in Time Series no Model is necessary. OpenQuery is enough. Important is not to forget the select **FLATTENED**.

thanks and br